# Git post-rebase hook

Tags: git, git-rebase

Is there such thing as post-rebase hook? My goal is that I want a script to execute after 
`git pull --rebase`
 command is used.

Answer (score 15):

Seems like post-rewrite hook does the job.

Comment: Did you get this working? When I pull and it just ffws my branch with new changes, no conflicts, my hook doesn't seem to be triggered.

Comment: It kinda worked for me...But not always...I don't know why it failed to trigger sometimes (rare occasions), since I did not investigate that. But still most of the time it did what it had to.

Comment: @user82116 ff is just a checkout of a newer commit, so post-checkout hook should be triggered i believe

Answer (score 5):

A `post-checkout` hook could work too, but only with with Git 2.21 (Q1 2019): "`git rebase`" internally runs "`checkout`" to switch between branches, and **the command used to call the `post-checkout` hook, but the reimplementation (from shell script to C)  stopped doing so**, which is getting fixed.

See [commit 8581df6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8581df65ec961aa59004f2d6342709b25d7b79c4), [commit 10499a9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/10499a9d586b3fba4ea6f67cd0b391b9e7048f34) (29 Dec 2018) by [Orgad Shaneh (`orgads`)](https://github.com/orgads).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit d94ade7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d94ade7f1f30409adecf8bdbae74d85cfb9705ef), 29 Jan 2019)</sup>

> `rebase`: run `post-checkout` hook on checkout
>
> The scripted version of rebase used to run this hook on the initial checkout.
>   The transition to built-in introduced a regression.

---

With Git 2.27 (Q2 2020), "`git rebase`" happens to call some hooks meant for "`checkout`" and "`commit`" by this was not a designed behaviour than historical accident.

> This has been documented.

See [commit f7139e7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f7139e7cc2d97a18f1bccfe48c4a270372917c91) (05 Apr 2020) by [Elijah Newren (`newren`)](https://github.com/newren).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 1779d18](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1779d181b51252ff853b00b6ad95c6641f7bef2b), 28 Apr 2020)</sup>

> ### [`git-rebase.txt`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f7139e7cc2d97a18f1bccfe48c4a270372917c91): add another hook to the hooks section, and explain more
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Elijah Newren</sup>
>
> For more discussion about these hooks, their history relative to rebase, and logical consistency between different types of operations, see this [git mailing-list thread](https://lore.kernel.org/git/CABPp-BG0bFKUage5cN_2yr2DkmS04W2Z9Pg5WcROqHznV3XBdw@mail.gmail.com/) and the links to some threads referenced therein.

The [`git rebase` hook section](https://github.com/git/git/blob/f7139e7cc2d97a18f1bccfe48c4a270372917c91/Documentation/git-rebase.txt#L683-L697) now includes:

> ### Hooks
>
> **The `apply` backend has not traditionally called the `post-commit` hook, while the `merge` backend has**.
>
> Both have called the `post-checkout` hook, though the merge backend has squelched its output.
>
> Further, both backends only call the post-checkout hook with the starting point commit of the rebase, not the intermediate commits nor the final commit.
>   In each case, the calling of these hooks was by accident of implementation rather than by design (both backends were originally implemented as shell scripts and happened to invoke other commands like '`git checkout`' or '`git commit`' that would call the hooks).
>
> **Both backends should have the same behavior**, though it is not entirely
>   clear which, if any, is correct.
>   **We will likely make rebase stop calling either of these hooks in the future.**