# How do I run a command when an interactive Git rebase is finished?

Tags: git, shell, git-rebase

I have a shell script that wraps `git rebase --interactive` and I’d like it to do some things after the rebase is complete. (I want it to notify the user if there are differences between the initial and final contents of the repo.) However, it’s not possible to just write

```
git rebase --interactive some_commit
# ...check for differences here...
```

because if the user opts to edit any commits, or if there are any conflicts that need to be resolved, then `git` will exit at that point and the following lines will be run, even though conceptually the rebase is not done yet.

I thought about installing a temporary “post-rebase” hook, but there is no such hook. The answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21307744/371228) suggest that a post-rewrite hook will work in some circumstances. However, I would want to clean up the hook even if the user ran `git rebase --abort` or `git rebase --quit`, and I assume the post-rewrite hook will not fire in these situations. (I don’t want to install permanent hooks to support this script, because I’d like the script to work on any repo without any setup needed beforehand. Besides, some of my repos already use post-checkout hooks to do unrelated things.)

Is there a way to get Git to run a certain script when a rebase finishes?

Comment: You should be able to manually add an `exec` line to the rebase instructions. To automate *that*, set the env variable `GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR` to the name of a script that will (1) open and edit the file in place to add the `exec` line, then (2) exec the editor you prefer.

Comment: i'd probably make the sequence editor append the line *after* the manual step, `GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR='f() { ${GIT_EDITOR-${EDITOR-vim}} "$@"; echo exec myscript "$@" >>"$1"; }; f'`.

Comment: @torek Thank you for mentioning the environment variable! I incorporated that into my solution and was able to make it much shorter that way.

Comment: @jthill One advantage of appending the `exec` line before opening the editor is that the user can opt out of running the script if they want to. In my original example of checking for changes, the user might already know that they’re going to introduce changes and so they wouldn’t bother running the script at the end. For other situations, though, unconditionally adding the script after the user edits the todo list might be preferable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to have two separate scripts: the one that kicks off `git rebase --interactive` (the “wrapper script”) and one that will be run at the end of the rebase (the “post-rebase script”). You can insert an `exec` line into the rebase todo list to ensure that the latter is run automatically at the end of the rebase. Furthermore, you can set the GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR environment variable to automate the addition of the `exec` line itself.

### The post-rebase script

Take the logic that should be run at the end of a rebase and put it into a separate script. (Note that this script will not be run if the rebase is aborted or quit.) If the script needs any context other than what’s available in the environment during a rebase, it should accept this information as command-line arguments.

For example, my shell script is called `check_git_diff` and it looks like

```
#!/usr/bin/env zsh

if [[ $# -ne 1 ]]; then
    print >&2 "usage: check_git_diff ORIGINAL_HEAD"
    exit 1
fi

readonly original_head=$1

if ! git diff --quiet $original_head HEAD; then
    kind='non-whitespace'
    if git diff --quiet --ignore-all-space $original_head HEAD; then
        kind='whitespace'
    fi
    print -P >&2 "%F{red}Warning:%f There are $kind differences from the original HEAD. See"
    print -P >&2 "\n  %F{blue}git diff $original_head HEAD%f\n"
fi
```

### Calling this script automatically

You can ask Git itself to run this script at the end of the rebase by adding an `exec` line to the end of the todo list. After all the `pick`, `squash`, `fixup`, etc. lines, add one for the post-rebase script:

```
pick 8bbfd15 update build instructions
pick caf5bfd frobnicate some additional blobs

exec check_git_diff caf5bfd3d4b6099aeed13604936976e610a08e18

# Rebase 9f594d2..caf5bfd onto 8bbfd15 (2 commands)
#
# ...
```

As you can see, you can include arguments to the post-rebase script if you need to.

If you run `git rebase --abort` or `git rebase --quit`, Git will stop running these commands, which is why I said above that `check_git_diff` will only be run at the conclusion of a *successful* rebase.

### Automatically calling this script automatically

Since it’s your script that’s kicking off `git rebase --interactive` in the first place, you have the opportunity to automate the previous step. In the wrapper script, set the GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR environment variable prior to calling `git rebase --interactive`. For example,

```
original_head=$(git rev-parse HEAD)
export GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR="f() {
    sed -i -e '/^$/a exec check_git_diff $original_head\n' \$1 && exec vim \$1
}; f"
```

If the GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR environment variable is set, Git will use its value as the name of the editor to use to edit the todo list. Typically you’d set this to something like `vim` or `emacs`, but here I’m actually defining a shell function and then using that function as the editor. (Git uses Bash to run the contents of GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR.) The shell function does two things: it calls `sed` to modify the todo list to include the `exec` line, and then it runs Vim so that you can edit the todo list like normal. Of course, you can replace `vim` with the name of your preferred editor.

The net effect is that you can run some certain logic before the interactive rebase starts, and then run some certain other logic after it successfully ends.

*Thank you to @torek for bringing the GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR variable to my attention. That makes the solution a lot simpler!*

Comment: I haven't read in detail your full setup ; if part of your need is to insert an `exec` action after each commit, `git rebase` got you covered : `git rebase -i --exec 'check_git_diff'`. You should be able to read the hashes of the original commits from the sequencer files, stored in `.git/rebase-merge`

Comment: @LeGEC I did discover that while reading the man page; see the last sentence of the answer :-) Unfortunately, I want to add just one `exec` command at the end of the list, not after every `pick` (or other action).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I like this, but perhaps this idea inspires someone to write something nice...

A wrapper shell script for `git rebase -i` could do something along the lines of

```
git_rebase_in_progress() {
    [[ -d "$(git rev-parse --git-path rebase-merge)" || -d "$(git rev-parse --git-path rebase-apply)" ]]
}

if git rebase --interactive ...
then
    while git_rebase_in_progress
    do
        echo "Rebase is in progress, exit 1 to abort the rebase, or run the normal interactive rebase commands like 'git rebase --skip' or 'git rebase --continue"
        # TODO: Set the shell prompt to indicate the following is not a normal shell
        if ${SHELL}
        then
            echo "Successful rebase step by user, continuing the rebase"
            continue
        else
            echo "User has aborted the rebase."
            break
        fi
    done
    echo "Rebase has finished, running special commands"
    # special commands go here
else
    echo "The rebase has failed."
fi
```

Comment: But the rebase is not necessarily “finished” when the shell thinks it is. If you add a “break” or “edit” line to the todo file, Git will exit at that point to allow you to make your changes. From the shell’s point of view, Git has exited and the shell should run the next command in the script. But the rebase is not done yet and it would not be correct to start doing post-rebase tasks at that point.

Comment: Good point. So one still needs to detect whether the interactive rebase is still in progress. If that specific thing is too difficult to figure out, detecting a detached HEAD should be a good proxy criterion.

Comment: I think `[[ -d "$(git rev-parse --git-path rebase-merge)" || -d "$(git rev-parse --git-path rebase-apply)" ]]` suffices to detect whether a rebase is in progress. But that doesn’t help to answer the question of “how do I ensure that some command is run once the rebase is finished?”.